# Unable to use sudo on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Please, how do i solve this issue.i recently had problems booting to my ubuntu 22.04 so i reinstalled it.after the installation, i've been unable to use sudo. i get the below error

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

Comment: You've broken the permissions in your system directory. Did you do a `chmod -R ...` at some point?

Comment: To start with, you can use a LIVE USB of Ubuntu or any other distro, mount the root file system, and then change the permissions of the sudoers files, boot back into your Ubuntu 22.04 installation, and go from there. If you did, in fact, run chmod -R across `/etc`, then like roaima said, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: Yes I did chmod 777 -R on my home directory because I was trying to upgrade boot into my windows so I have to update the grub. But I’ve been able to solve the issue now by reinstalling the ubuntu and updating the grub during installation. Everything is working fine now.